# Classical probability problem

Tags: probability

Q. If (1+3p)/3 , (1-p)/4 , (1-2p)/2 are the probabilities of the three mutually exclusive events, then p belongs to :-

1. [0,1]
2. [0,1/2]
3. [1/3,1]
4. [1/3,1/2]

Please if anyone could post an explanation. Thank you.

Comment: what do you know about the probabilities of  mutually exclusive events?

Comment: that they are disjoint and share no common event between them I guess?@roberttimmer-arends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If three mutually exclusive events be A, B, C then $P(A+B+C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)$ since $P(A+B+C)\le 1$ so we have,
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ8eP.png)[image]

Comment: Thank for the help!